# Rounded rectangle in shader editor?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, shaders, mathematics

How can I create a rounded rectangle with Width, Height, Radius parameters based on the UV coords? For example, on a simple plane

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about Specific Parameters (values) for height, width and radius, but you can get a reasonable amount of control by adjusting the ColorRamps in this setup:

[image: Rect]

Answer (score 2):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

The centre, width, height and radius parameters are hard-coded by the left hand side nodes. Three masks are combined, one for the horizontal rectangular part, one for the vertical rectangular part, and one for the corner disks.

[image: Shading nodes graph]

**Resources:** [image]